# mistake with downloading pdf file safari

Tags: javascript, angular

I have angular application. I need to save Blob file from server to user. All browser works, without Safari

I received response: Blob and save

```
  this.blobURL = this.sanitizer.sanitize(
        SecurityContext.URL,
        this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
          window.URL.createObjectURL(response)
        )
      );
```

I run

```
download() {
    if (!this.blobURL) return;

    const anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.href = this.blobURL;
    anchor.target = '_blank';
    anchor.setAttribute(
      'download',
      `test.pdf`
    );
    const event = new MouseEvent('click');
    anchor.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

It incorrect works for safari, file opened but didn't download

I tried use new Blob and ngx-filesaver, but after download i opened file i have mistake -  Failed to load PDF document.

```
    const data = new Blob([this.blobURL], {
      type: 'application/pdf',
    });
    this.fileSaverService.save(
      data,
      `test.pdf`
    );
  }
```

or

```
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(
      new Blob([this.blobURL], { type: 'application/pdf' })
    );
    window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on the part about the "Failed to load PDF document?"  Could this be an issue with the file you are testing with?  Can you try a different file from the server?

Answer (score 0):

I found working solution for me

```js
    fileUrl;
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        // receive data from backend
        const blob = new Blob([data], {
            type: 'application/octet-stream'
        });
        this.fileUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    }
```

```html
<a [href]="fileUrl" download="file.pdf">DownloadFile</a>
```